# Making a simple music bot for discord server, not working

Tags: node.js

Working on making a bot for a personal discord server, wanting it to simply join general voicechat when command "Blyat" is detected, play mp3 file, when its done to leave. Code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var client = new Discord.Client();
var isReady = true;

client.on('message', message => {
    if (command === "Blyat") {
        var VC = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!VC) return message.reply("MESSAGE IF NOT IN A VOICE CHANNEL")
        VC.join()
            .then(connection => {
                const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:\Users\Wyatt\Music\soviet-anthem.mp3');
                dispatcher.on("finish", end => { VC.leave() });
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    };
});

client.login('token, not putting in code, is there in real code');
```

> Error: "ReferenceError: command is not defined
> at Client. (C:\Users\jeffofBread\Desktop\Discord Bot\main.js:6:5)"

Any help or tips will be much appreciated, haven't coded in many years and have lost any knowledge I had once held.

Comment: where the `command` defined in first `if` statement? if you want to detect text start with "Blyat" on message, check `if(message.content.startsWith("Blyat")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from an unidentified variable. Fortunatly that is very easy to fix. All you have to do is define `command` before you call it.

For this we'll splice the message content into two parts. The command and any arguments that may be included like mentions or other words. We do that with:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

*Note: The `args` constant is an array.*

Which would make your entire `onMessage` event look like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const prefix = "!";
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "blyat") {
        var VC = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!VC) return message.reply("MESSAGE IF NOT IN A VOICE CHANNEL")
        VC.join()
            .then(connection => {
                const dispatcher = connection.play('C:\Users\Wyatt\Music\soviet-anthem.mp3');
                dispatcher.on("finish", end => { VC.leave() });
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    };
});
```

Comment: Now it says prefix undefined, though seems the command is now defined.

Comment: oh yes, my bad. You need to set a prefix somewhere before you call it. If you don't want a prefix you can just take out `.slice(prefix.length)`.

Comment: Thanks! No more errors, but now simply does nothing. maybe an issue with the join command?

Comment: probably not, you need to make sure the command `command === "blyat"` is all lowercase or remove `.toLowerCase();`. I also noticed that your voicechannel is defined incorrectly. I edited the answer, this should work now.

Comment: Still not working. Going to make a new post dedicated to the new issue, because the original one at hand is fixed. Reason im wondering if its a voice channel command issue or maybe even a permission error is its not even joining our general voice chat.

Comment: Note: have to wait to post next thread, 90 minute cooldown on making threads.